# Bring Text Area column for entering the comment to the same column position of other column in the form

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core

I have a form with  two column in each row and finally a single column in a single row which for entering the comment using text area. I am trying to start  text area column with same column position index of other column. But  the text area will be not be showing the same column index of other columns. Please help. I have attached  the image here and also my code here with

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">Make</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="Make" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm row">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Model</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="Model" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group  row">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">Reg.No</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="RegNo" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group  row">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="VehicleName" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group  row">
                <label for="MOTDate" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">MOT Date</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="MOTDate" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="TaxDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Tax Date</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="TaxDate" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="InsuredDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Date insured</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="InsuredDate" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="RegDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Reg Date</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="RegDate" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
     

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="Comment" class="control-label col-2 col-form-label">Comment</label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <textarea asp-for="Comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change column distribution in your code. I have uploaded, check changes in code for textarea only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group  row">
            <label for="inputName" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">Reg.No</label>
            <div class="col-9">
               <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                  asp-for="RegNo" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group  row">
            <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
            <div class="col-9">
               <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                  asp-for="VehicleName" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group  row">
            <label for="MOTDate" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">MOT Date</label>
            <div class="col-9">
               <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                  asp-for="MOTDate" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="TaxDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Tax Date</label>
            <div class="col-9">
               <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                  asp-for="TaxDate" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="InsuredDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Date insured</label>
            <div class="col-9">
               <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                  asp-for="InsuredDate" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="RegDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Reg Date</label>
            <div class="col-9">
               <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                  asp-for="RegDate" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Comment" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Comment</label>
            <div class="col-9">
               <textarea asp-for="Comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. But  is there anyway can we can I  show the text area in full width of the  col-md-12  without splitting  col-md-6

Answer (score 0):

`col-3` in `col-md-6` equals `col-1.5` in `col-md-12`. You can customize `col-1.5` and `col-10.5` like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    .custom-label-col {
        width: 12.5%;
        flex: 0 0 12.5%;
        max-width: 12.5%;
    }

    .custom-area-col {
        width: 87.5%;
        flex: 0 0 87.5%;
        max-width: 87.5%;
    }
</style>

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">Make</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="Make" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm row">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Model</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="Model" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group  row">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">Reg.No</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="RegNo" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group  row">
                <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="VehicleName" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group  row">
                <label for="MOTDate" class="control-label  col-3 col-form-label">MOT Date</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="MOTDate" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="TaxDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Tax Date</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="TaxDate" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="InsuredDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Date insured</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="InsuredDate" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="RegDate" class="control-label col-3 col-form-label">Reg Date</label>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="inputName"
                           asp-for="RegDate" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
     

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="Comment" class="control-label col custom-label-col col-form-label">Comment</label>
                <div class="col custom-area-col">
                    <textarea asp-for="Comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
```